# Converting WinForms App to WebForm App

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms, listview, gridview

Previously i was working on Windows Form based application in .Net. Now i am developing the same app in ASP.Net.

The issue is, in WinForms, i had functionality which is like this:-

1. ListView was present in the MainForm. When a user clicks on that ListView, another form was going to pop-up, which is also a WinForm. (For this form i was sending a Bill Object as reference)
2. In the pop-up form, the user will select a particular Billable Item and click on a button called "Add".(This Billable Item is going to be saved in Bill Object)
3. When this button is clicked, an event is fired in the MainForm. This event was going to add the Billable Item (the one which user has selected in the pop-up Form) into the ListView using the 'Bill Object', without even closing the pop-up form.
4. This procedure will continue until the user manually closes the pop-up Form.

My issue is, i do not know how to realize this or make this work in Web Application using ASP.Net with vb in code behind. I am using Content Page.

I know i can use GridView in asp.net, just like ListView in WinForm.

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Thank You,
Mayur

Comment: There is a significant difference between Win Forms and Web Forms.  I would suggest starting by getting to know and understand the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) of a Web Form.  It's not an easy jump to go from one to the other, but it's doable.

Comment: I had to face the same problem. I strongly recommend taking a look at ASP.Net MVC (along with html/javascript) and not WebForms. It's obsolete and it's difficult to understand what's really going on underneath. This is my valuable suggestion. Look here about modal popup anyway: http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: @Vland Thank you. i will consider doing it in MVC.

Comment: @Vland - WebForms is by no means obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASP.net` was designed to be familiar to `WinForms` developers which is why you have many of the same control names. In actuality, this is often a hindrance as there are significant differences between many `ASP.net` webcontrols and their `WinForms` counterparts.

In addition the `page lifecycle` that is at the heart of `ASP.net` webforms is a very different model to what you would be used to with `WinForms`.

I suggest starting with the official `ASP.net` learning resources. They're a great introduction to the two main ASP.net approaches:

- Webforms: http://www.asp.net/web-forms
- MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc